# Organizing the order of method completion in a different method Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I have a problem in my app which crashes is it because it calls the rest of the method before the first method is done. Here is where the error happens:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        fetchLastLocation();

        LManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        currentLocation = getLastKnownLocation();

        suppMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.maps);
        suppMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


@Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
        this.mMap = googleMap;
        CheckGps();
        LatLng latLng = null;

        if(currentLocation == null)
        {
            currentLocation = getLastKnownLocation();
            latLng = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
        }
        else{
            latLng = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
        }

        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("You are here!");
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 12));
        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
```

In the `OnCreate` method it runs a method called `fetchLastLocaiton()` which asks the phone for the permission to use the location, but the `OnMapReadyCallback()` crashes the app before the `fetchLastLocaiton()` is called and given a response, thus causing the app to crash the first time you start the app, and causes crashes everytime you run the app without Location being turned on your phone(Which the `CheckGps()` method checks).

Could AsyncTask or a new Thread inside the method help? Or is it an error somewhere else in my code? If so here is the rest of the code:

```
package com.example.ilovemilfs;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.wifi.hotspot2.pps.HomeSp;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.TextureView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResolvableApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsResponse;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;
import java.util.jar.Attributes;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    GoogleMap mMap;
    SupportMapFragment suppMapFragment;
    Location currentLocation;
    FusedLocationProviderClient client;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 101;
    LocationRequest locationRequest;
    private LocationManager LManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        fetchLastLocation();

        LManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);



        currentLocation = getLastKnownLocation();

        suppMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.maps);
        suppMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    private void fetchLastLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE);
            CheckGps();
            return;
        }
        Task<Location> task = client.getLastLocation();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                if (location != null) {
                    currentLocation = location;
                    suppMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.maps);
                    suppMapFragment.getMapAsync(MainActivity.this);
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
        this.mMap = googleMap;
        CheckGps();
        LatLng latLng = null;

        if(currentLocation == null)
        {
            currentLocation = getLastKnownLocation();
            latLng = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
        }
        else{
            latLng = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
        }

        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("You are here!");
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 12));
        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    private void CheckGps() {
        locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(5000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(3000);

        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder().addLocationRequest(locationRequest).setAlwaysShow(true);

        Task<LocationSettingsResponse> locationSettingsResponseTask = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(getApplicationContext()).checkLocationSettings(builder.build());

        locationSettingsResponseTask.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task) {
                try {
                    LocationSettingsResponse response = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Gps is already enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } catch (ApiException e) {
                    if (e.getStatusCode() == LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED) {
                        ResolvableApiException resolvableApiException = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                        try {
                            resolvableApiException.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, 101);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException ex) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                        }
                    }
                    if (e.getStatusCode() == LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Setting not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    fetchLastLocation();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 101) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "GPS is enabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Denied GPS permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }


    public void ibLokacija(View view) {
        CheckGps();
    }

    public void ibRefreshRef(View view) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void ibHospital(View view) {
        NearbyHospitals();
    }


    public void NearbyHospitals() {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        Location l = this.currentLocation;

        executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                    String uri = "https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json][timeout:25];(node%5B%22amenity%22%3D%22hospital%22%5D(around%3A10000%2C%20"
                            + String.valueOf(l.getLatitude()) + "%2C%20"
                            + String.valueOf(l.getLongitude()) + ");)%3Bout%20body;";

                    URL url = new URL(uri);

                    HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                    InputStream inputStream = (InputStream) huc.getContent();
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "utf-8"));
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;
                    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                        stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    inputStream.close();
                    String string = stringBuilder.toString();

                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Hospitals(string);
                        }
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private void Hospitals(String s) {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

        GoogleMap googleMap = this.mMap;

        executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("elements");
                    Integer integer = jsonArray.length();
                    String s1 = integer.toString();
                    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject locationJSON1 = jsonObject1.getJSONObject("tags");
                        String name = null;

                        if(locationJSON1.isNull("name")){
                            name = "Hospital";
                        }
                        else{
                            name = locationJSON1.getString("name");
                        }

                        String lat_street = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("lat");
                        String lon_housenumber = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("lon");
                        LatLng latLng = null;

                        if(lat_street != null && lon_housenumber  != null){
                            latLng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(lat_street), Double.parseDouble(lon_housenumber));
                        }
                        else if(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).isNull("lat") && jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).isNull("lon") && locationJSON1.isNull("addr:street") && locationJSON1.isNull("addr:housenumber")){
                            latLng = getLocationFromName(MainActivity.this, name);
                        }
                        else{
                            lat_street = locationJSON1.getString("addr:street");
                            lon_housenumber = locationJSON1.getString("addr:housenumber");
                            latLng = getLocationFromAddress(MainActivity.this, lat_street + lon_housenumber);
                        }

                        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                        markerOptions.title(name);
                        markerOptions.position(latLng);


                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                            }
                        });

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public LatLng getLocationFromAddress(Context context, String strAddress){
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context);
        List<Address> addresses;
        LatLng latLng = null;

        try{
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(strAddress, 10);
            if(addresses == null){
                return null;
            }
            Address location = addresses.get(0);
            location.getLatitude();
            location.getLongitude();

            latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return latLng;
    }

    public LatLng getLocationFromName(Context context, String name){
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context);
        List<Address> addresses = null;
        LatLng latLng = null;

        try{
            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocationName(name, 10);
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            address.getLatitude();
            address.getLongitude();

            latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return latLng;
    }

    private Location getLastKnownLocation(){
        Location l = null;
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        List<String> providers = locationManager.getProviders(true);
        Location betterLocation = null;
        for(String provider : providers){
            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                l = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            }
            if(l == null){
                continue;
            }
            if(betterLocation == null || l.getAccuracy() < betterLocation.getAccuracy()){
                betterLocation = l;
            }
        }
        return betterLocation;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's like you say, after you start the permission request the rest of your code is executed. The actual results of the permission request come *later*, through a call to `onRequestPermissionsResult`. The app can't pause execution to wait for that result, the user making a decision etc - it would just be a frozen app, which is why it happens asynchronously instead.

That means you need to write your app to work asynchonously too. **You can't** just call the stuff in `onCreate` that relies on the permission being granted, because if the user hasn't been asked yet, you have to wait until that's taken care of. You have to defer that task until you're ready to execute it.

The simplest way is just to stick it in a function, and then call it when ready:

```
protected void initialiseMap() {
    currentLocation = getLastKnownLocation();
    suppMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.maps);
    suppMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

(I don't actually know which lines need to be deferred, and which can be safely called in `onCreate` - you can work that out!)

Now you can call that function whenever it's suitable. One possibility is to do it during the permission check - if you check it and everything's cool (e.g. already granted) you can immediately call the function and finish up. You're actually already doing something like that in `fetchLastLocation()` - your `OnSuccessListener` contains the same code as in `onCreate`. I don't know how your task works, but if it calls that code soon after, it doesn't need to be in `onCreate` anyway, right? And now you can just call the `initialiseMap` function instead.

---

You also need to handle the situation where permission isn't granted, and it comes through later. You're sort of doing that too - `onRequestPermissionsResult` calls `fetchLastLocation` when the request is successful. Since that should immediately fall through to the task that calls `initialiseMap`, it should work fine. (And because you're calling this function again, so it's where the initialisation happens in every case, maybe you don't need the separate `initialiseMap` function at all).

---

But don't forget you also need to handle the situation where permission **isn't** granted. You have to decide what that should look like, how things should look while you're waiting (e.g. in `fetchLastLocation`, if you're putting in the permission request you might want to call a function that displays some "pending" state). And also how things should look if permission was actively denied (e.g. in `onRequestPermissionsResult`, calling a function that displays a warning, an empty map view etc).

---

That was a lot of words to say *"you've pretty much already got it, you're handling the initialisation conditionally, just don't call the initialisation stuff in `onCreate` as well where it will **always** run"* - but hopefully it helps make the flow clearer, and the different routes through your code depending on what's happening. You just need to make sure the initialisation only happens at the right points in that code, when it's definitely safe to do so!

Comment: sorry for the late answer, I was away, but anyway, your suggestion worked!! Thank you very much for your help!!